# How to find rolling difference for different Categories present inside a Pandas Datafarame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

[image]

I have a dataframe like this (as an example). Now I want to find the first order difference in Profit for each of Delhi and Kolkata. Basically, I want to calculate the percentage change in Profit from 2020 to 2021 and from 2021 to 2022 for each of those 2 categories and present the same in the same dataframe.

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks.

I tried using .diff() but that will consider the difference for all the Categories in Region and not separately for each category.

Comment: Please can you provide input data and not screenshot

Comment: Use groupby and pct_change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_pct_change`:

```
df['pct'] = df.sort_values('cat2').groupby('cat1')['Profit'].pct_change()
print(df)

# Output
   Profit     cat1  cat2        pct
0    1.28    Delhi  2020        NaN
1   17.78    Delhi  2021  12.890625
2   43.37    Delhi  2022   1.439258
3    0.69  Kolkata  2020        NaN
4   10.11  Kolkata  2021  13.652174
5   23.35  Kolkata  2022   1.309594
```

**Note**: if you want percentage, don't forget to multiply by 100.